# Regex to transform URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url

I have a string that comes into a method that is part of a URL building class and vary greatly.  Out of those variable cases I want to capture a string that comes in like this:

```
/MODEL(guid)
```

and convert it to look like

```
/MODEL?id=guid
```

My question is what would be the best method to capture only the strings that come into the method that look like "/MODEL(guid)" - model being anything, guid being any guid and transform them to look like the above?  For example:

`/ACCOUNT(d60c0dbb-426d-4971-86a6-0fd9d8eaff91)` should be converted to

```
/ACCOUNT?id=d60c0dbb-426d-4971-86a6-0fd9d8eaff91
```

If any string comes into the method that does not have a section that looks like the first example it should be ignored.  I would assume some sort of regex but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: A simple search for a regex to match a guid should get you a long way to your goal. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Matt, I need to match not only the GUID it needs to match:

/ANYWORD( GUID )

Comment: Willing to know if you have tried something.

Comment: I have tried using split on "(":

var pathArray = path.split('(')

and then testing to see if the 2 item in the resluting array contains a GUID + ")" but it doesn't seem right to me.

I end up with 2 items in the array:

[0] = "/MODEL"
[1]= "d60c0dbb-426d-4971-86a6-0fd9d8eaff91)"

but this only works on the case that the incoming string happens to have the "/MODEL(GUID)" format.

Comment: `str = str.replace(/(\/\w+)\(([^)]+)\)/g, '$1?id=$2');`

Comment: if you put this as an answer I will select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this code:

```js
let str = '/ACCOUNT(d60c0dbb-426d-4971-86a6-0fd9d8eaff91)';
str = str.replace(/(\/\w+)\(([^)]+)\)/g, '$1?id=$2');

console.log(str);
//=> /ACCOUNT?id=d60c0dbb-426d-4971-86a6-0fd9d8eaff91
```

Regex `(\/\w+)\(([^)]+)\)/` uses 2 capture groups:

1. `(\/\w+)`is 1st group that matches URL segment that starts with `/` followed by 1+ word characters
2. `\(([^)]+)\)` has 2nd group surrounded by literal `(` and `)`

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest something along the lines of:

```
/(?!\/[\w\d]+)\(([\w\d]{8}\-([\w\d]{4}\-){3}[\w\d]{12})\)/
```

e.g.

```js
let a = /(?!\/[\w\d]+)\(([\w\d]{8}\-([\w\d]{4}\-){3}[\w\d]{12})\)/;
let b = "/ACCOUNT(d60c0dbb-426d-4971-86a6-0fd9d8eaff91)";
let result = b.replace(a, "?id=$1");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eazy:

```
var string = '/ACCOUNT(d60c0dbb-426d-4971-86a6-0fd9d8eaff91)';
var matches = string.match(/\/(.*)\((.*)\)/);

var new_string = `/${matches[1]}?id=${matches[2]}`
```

Answer (score 0):

So do you need a Java or Js function ? For both I would use split
For java : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_split.htm
For Js : https://javascript.info/regexp-methods

In Js it would give something like :

```
var inString = "/Account(id123)"
splitArray = inString.split("(");
```

It will give you an array with 2 values : "/Account" and "id123)"

Simply remove the last char using slice then concat to create your string

```
var id = splitArray[1].slice(0,-1)
var newUrl = splitArray[0]+"?id="+id
```